# How to populate table view with custom object?

Tags: swift, uitableview, codable

I have a struct that conforms to the Codable protocol. I make an URLSession request and receive an JSON response. I encode the response into my custom struct that looks something like this.

```
struct Weather: Codable {
    let time: Date
    let location: String
    let timeEvents: [TimeEvents]
}  

struct TimeEvents: Codable {
    let validTime: Date
    let parameters: [Parameters]
}

struct Parameters: Codable {
    let name: String
    let unit: String
    let values: [Double]
}
```

I get a single object Weather. However, inside the object Weather I want to populate the `validTime`, *i.e.* `01/01/2018 12:00`, with the corresponding `name` matching "temperature" and corresponding `values`, *i.e.* `10.5 C`.

So the rows will look something like:

```
[01/01/2018 12:00 : 10.5C]
[01/01/2018 13:00 : 11.5C]
[01/01/2018 14:00 : 11.6C]
.
.
.
[02/01/2018 00:00 : 3.1C]
[02/01/2018 01:00 : 3.1C]
```

In my controller I have something like:

```
var testWeatherObject : [Weather] = []
```

I only want a single header at the top displaying a single location *i.e.* New York.

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return testWeatherObject[section].timeEvents.count
}
```

The above crashes my app. I'm not sure how to get the correct row counts.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WeatherDataCell", for: indexPath)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Didn't you forget to register cell in viewDidLoad?

Comment: It's rare to see an up-voted question with **four** answers, none of which are accepted.  More, you haven't indicated that anything helped. Care to offer some input?

Comment: @dfd just had time to go through them. Already accepted an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may access an empty array so

```
return testWeatherObject.first?.timeEvents.count ?? 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have just single section, you don't have to set this. Delete these lines of code:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

And now if you want to have single table view cell for each timeEvent you should create your weather object

```
var testWeatherObject = // your Weather object
```

and in data source method numberOfRowInSection just say I want as many cells as testWeatherObject has timeEvents

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return testWeatherObject.timeEvents.count
}
```

However I recommend not to use your Weather object as variable. Instead you should create array of TimeEvents

```
var timeEvents = [/* your TimeEvents objects*/]
```

and in table view data source method use just this

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return timeEvents.count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have sections you don't need to implement `numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView)`

If you're only working with a single Weather object why not change the definition of testWeatherObject to

```
var testWeatherObject = [TimeEvents]
```

and your `numberOfRowsInSection` would then become

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return testWeatherObject.count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s crashing because you’re trying to access a nested array that is empty.

I would check to see if `testWeatherObjects.count` is `0` first. If not then you can go ahead and use `testWeatherObject[section].timeEvents.count`

Answer (score 0):

Does the identifier of cell defined in storyboard or xib match "WeatherDataCell"?

I made a simple tableview app sample.
https://github.com/y-okudera/TableViewDemoApp

I hope to be helpful.